# Javascript function not working properly in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, safari

On Load of Access.aspx a javascript function is called.

```
<head>
<title>access</title>
<meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
<meta content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
<meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
<meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
<link href="rtsBanner.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="winopen.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function openLogin(site, pass) {
        var loginUrl = 'login.aspx';
        if (site != '' && pass != '') {
            loginUrl += '?SITE=' + site + '&PASS=' + pass;
        }
        else if (site != '') {
            loginUrl += '?SITE=' + site;
        }
        var popUpFeatures = 'dialogHeight: 385px; dialogWidth: 600px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: No; scroll: Yes; status: No;';
        var RetVal = window.showModalDialog(loginUrl, 'null', popUpFeatures);
        if (typeof (RetVal) == 'undefined') {
            top.window.close();
        }
        else {
            var RetArray = RetVal.split(',')
            var ValidLogon = RetArray[0];
            var MUName = RetArray[1];
            if (ValidLogon == 1) {
                document.location.href = 'newRequest.aspx?desc=' + MUName;
            }
            else {
                top.window.close();
            }
        } // else(typeof(RetVal)
    }
</script>

</head>
<body ms_positioning="GridLayout" onload="openLogin('<%=Request("SITE")%>','<%=Request("PASS")%>');">
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
&nbsp;
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works perfectly in IE but in safari on the login screen after I enter site name and password and hit login button it doesn't redirect me to the newRequest.aspx page instead just closes the login popup and shows a blank access.aspx page.

Editted:

This is the code on btnLogin_Click on Login.aspx.vb page

```
If txtSiteName.Text = "" And txtPassPhrase.Text = "" Then Return
        If ValidateSiteAndPass(txtSiteName.Text, txtPassPhrase.Text) = False Then
            Throw New Exception("OOPS!!! Either SiteName or Pass Phrase is Invalid, please check")
        Else
            Session("valid") = "true"
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>{window.returnValue='1," + txtSiteName.Text + "'; self.close();}</script>") '''document.Form1.submit();")
            Response.End()
        End If
```

Please suggest

Thanks,
Kavita

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console after this happens?

Comment: If PASS === PASSWORD: You are passing a password in the query string?

Comment: Your form seems to be a bit empty for me. And, do you really want to open a popup `onload`?

Comment: This is an old project and I was just moved to it. I am not sure why the popup is opening on load. There is really nothing on access.aspx page

Comment: Matt I tried to debug in the Safari Developer but its not showing any errors

Comment: If all else fails you can always set a breakpoint and single step the code in the debugger.

Comment: I found the problem..In case of Safari the typeof (RetVal) is always undefined so it always executes this block

    if (typeof (RetVal) == 'undefined') {
            top.window.close();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1400811.aspx/1

The problem was due to window.showModalDialog. It doesn't work properly in Safari.. I replaced it with window.open

Thanks,
Kavita